# Would "one cylinder's out" semantics include a head gasket?

Tags: engine, head-gasket

I sold a car on craigslist with part of the title being "Runs, but one cylinder's out". I had taken the car to Firestone to diagnose why one cylinder wasn't firing right and they said it has 0% compression, and to continue diagnosing and fixing is going to cost thousands of dollars, so I took it home and put it out for sale. I explained all this to the buyer. The buyer (long after the sale) then came back to me and said that the head gasket is out, and that this has nothing to do with the cylinder. She's very upset, though I don't know why since a head gasket failure is a lot cheaper than an actual ruptured cylinder.

To me, as a layman (I know very little about auto mechanics), when I say "the cylinder's out", such semantics are intended to suggest that there is a failure somewhere amongst the entire system of parts associated with a cylinder--actual cylinder itself, the piston, the fuel injector, the spark plug, the *head gasket*, such that the functionality of that part of the motor is not functioning correctly (not firing or zero torque)--but I might have made an incorrect assumption.

To you mechanics out there, do you expect that if a courtroom judge were to read the advertisement, "one cylinder's out", the judge should deem this to include a head gasket failure (rupture, chip, crack, etc)?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question are pretty much guaranteed to be entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Really? So if I said "does 'an exhaust pipe' include a car radio" that would be the same difference to you?
I'm not here to win SE points or to promote SE's special "ideal question" format, I'm here because I need practical perspective on a real-world problem.

Comment: "the cylinders out" might be a little ambiguous. but if you mentioned the low compression then i don't see any reason why you'd be at fault. the head gasket helps seal the cylinder to ensure maximum compression and prevent oil/coolant from leaking into the cylinder. so its fair to say that low compression might be caused by a blown gasket (among other things)

Comment: Also voted to close as opinion.This question isn't about motor vehicle maintenance.

Comment: I agree this is too far on the opinion side. That said, I would put the symptom in the ad (*one cylinder has zero compression*). You are letting the buyer know exactly without ambiguity, which the original statement has plenty. Zero compression is a specific issue, which tells the buyer what's going on, but leaves it on them to figure it out. Also, if only one cylinder is out, I would not put this in the realm of a head gasket. You'd still get *some* compression if the head gasket were the issue.

Comment: If you'd like to, this could ***easily*** and ***completely*** be discussed in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop).

Comment: Your morally and ethically clean IMO.